# Server is returning AWS cognito credentials

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on a android project in which server will ping AWS cogntio to get IdentityId and Token. Server code written in PHP. Using refresh method in AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider class I want to ping my server to get that Identity and token. Whenever the refresh method pings myserver the server has to connect to AWS cognito and get that Identity and token. Return that IdentityId and token to client. but it is not happening.
Here is my code:

Server Side:

```
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        use Aws\CognitoIdentity\CognitoIdentityClient;
        use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
        use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
        use Aws\S3\S3Client;

   $Client = CognitoIdentityClient::factory(array(
 'version' => 'latest',
 'profile'=> 'project1',
  'region'  => 'ap-northeast-1'
   ));

      $result = $Client->getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(array(
  'IdentityPoolId' => 'ap-northeast-1:b871fa5f-23a2-480d-baa6-b4ed31437244',
  'Logins' => array(
      'login.blupinch.app' => "7386372871",
  ),
  'TokenDuration' => 36000
  ));

  echo $result['IdentityId']."==".$result['Token'];

 }
```

Client side code :

```
  public class Auth extends AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider {


public Auth(String accountId, String identityPoolId, Regions region) {
    super(accountId, identityPoolId, region);


}


@Override
public String getProviderName() {
    return "login.blupinch.app";
}

public String refresh() {

    setToken(null);

    if (getProviderName() != null &&
            !this.loginsMap.isEmpty() &&
            this.loginsMap.containsKey(getProviderName())) {

            Idtoken();

        update(identityId, token);

        return token;



    } else {

        this.getIdentityId();
        return null;
    }
}

public String getIdentityId() {


    identityId = null;
    if (identityId == null) {


        if (getProviderName() != null && !this.loginsMap.isEmpty()
                && this.loginsMap.containsKey(getProviderName())) {

               Idtoken();
            update(identityId, token);
            return identityId;

        } else {
            return super.getIdentityId();
        }

    } else {
        return identityId;
    }

}

public void Idtoken(){

    String line = "";
    String response="";


    String serverurl = "http://10.0.3.2/credentials.php";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(serverurl);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoInput(true);



        InputStream IS = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS,"iso-8859-1"));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            response = response + line;

        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        IS.close();
        http.disconnect();
        String[] splitter = response.split("==");
        identityId = splitter[0];
        token = splitter[1];
        Log.d("IDENTITYID",identityId);
        Log.d("TOKEN",token);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Warnings:

```
           02-29 12:55:45.563 452-799/? W/AudioFlinger: write blocked for  10041 msecs, 6 delayed writes, thread 0xf58ba000
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.3.2/credentials.php
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sandesh.filer.UpDown.Auth.Idtoken(Auth.java:107)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sandesh.filer.UpDown.Auth.refresh(Auth.java:46)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:537)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:503)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:462)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sandesh.filer.UpDown.upload.doInBackground(upload.java:93) 
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at com.example.sandesh.filer.UpDown.upload.doInBackground(upload.java:28)    
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
           02-29 12:55:45.779 16968-17029/? W/System.err:     at              java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in an emulator, and you are trying to hit your server running on localhost, the IP address is 10.0.2.2

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But I am Using Genymotion. It is 10.0.3.2 .

Comment: AdditionalInfo:I have observed there is delay for server to ping aws cognito to get Identity Id and token. What I did was I have removed whole code except an echo "helloworld". Then ran refresh method. I found the string helloworld recieved as there is no delay needed get echo "helloworld".Is this delay makes problem? I have also found When I open server code (credentials.php) in browser. the IdentityId and Token are not getting printed in browser(Here echo is not at all working). But when i run it from command line like this php credentilas.php . It works fine. it echos Identity Id and token.